# Is it possible to use Apple Sign-In implementation without using ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton? Does it pass through the reviews?

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to use Apple Sign-In implementation without using **ASAuthorizationAppleIDButton**?

Does it pass through the reviews?

The designers are trying a new style for the button to sign in with Apple, and I would like to know if there is a problem besides consistent and familiar UI experience for users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your own sign-in button (I did it on my React Native apps) and it will pass through review as long as you fit minimal recommendation from Apple.

You can find these minimal recommendations [here](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sign-in-with-apple#Creating-a-custom-Sign-in-with-Apple-button)